# Hot Module Replacement cannot find dll reference

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hot-middleware, dllplugin

I use DllPlugin and DllReferencePlugin in our project, everything works fine with the first build. It means DLL works well. But when it comes to HMR, the generated hot-update.js is filled with:

```
var e = new Error(\"Cannot find module \\\"dll-reference vendor_2fbac64ff6173d91e522\\\"\")
```

In the console, it says: `[HMR] Cannot check for update (Full reload needed)`

I'm using webpack 3.4.1, a webpack compiler with webpackHotMiddleware@2.15.0, anyone had issue when use HMR and DLL together?